# How do I search a Firebase database reference for a certain value from children within children within children?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I'm trying to search for a certain value within multiple children within a Firebase database. For example, I have a database called collections, which contains different collections. Those collections contain different plants, and those plants contain plantTags, which contain certain values that I'm interested in.

[My Firebase JSON is included here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8ovB.png)

How do I search for a specific plantTags, say "water", and then display that specific plant's name and image on the web page for multiple plants that have a plantTag for "water"?

I was thinking something like

```
ref.collection.plants.orderbyChild("plantTags").equalTo("water").....
```

Or is it going to be more complex like iterating over all plant children in all collections to see if they have a plantTags child called "water"?

I'm also working on this project in Vue.js.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to keep firebase more shallow ie. allow plants to be the top-level document and give each plant sub-properties for collection and plant tags. This should allow orderbyChild to order all top-level plants by their child plantTags = water, for example.

Answer (score 0):

As Cuttsy27 proposed, you could denormalize your data. A good approach for implementing your requirements, would be to have, in addition to the `collections` node, an extra main node `plantTags` and have a child node for each plantTag with plants children nodes with the needed info:

```
- collections
    - ....
- plantTags
    - water
      - 1082 <- plantID
         - plantName: "........"
         - plantPic: "xxxxxxxx.png"
      - 362             
         - plantName: "........"
         - plantPic: "xxxxxxxx.png"
    - propagate
      - 362
         - plantName: "........"
         - plantPic: "xxxxxxxx.png"
      - 876             
         - plantName: "........"
         - plantPic: "xxxxxxxx.png"
```

In such a way it would be very easy to query for all the plants which have a given tag.

For example in "pure" JavaScript:

```
var tagToQuery = 'water';
var ref = database.ref('/plantTags/' + tagToQuery);
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        console.log(childData.name)
        // ...
    });
});
```

In order to maintain the two nodes in sync, use the `update` method (documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields) which allows to "simultaneously write to specific children of a node"

(Simple) example with your data structure:

```
  var updates = {};
  updates['/collections/0/plants/0'] =  ... ;
  updates['/plantTags/water/362] = ...;
  updates['/plantTags/propagate/362] = ...;

  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Comment: @Amy did you have the time to look at this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Array` -> Use `Dictionary` instead. Search can not be perform in `Array`. Instead of **0, 1, 2** use **autogenerated** keys everywhere.

Then you can query like

> collections -> collectionId -> plants -> yourQuery

Or redefine your db structure something like you can fetch this content. With current db its not possible to fetch the data until you know the each index of `collections` `(0, 1 or else)` and `plants` `(0, 1 or else)` to reach at the node.